# Ubuntu Touch Emulator for Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu-emulator

The [Ubuntu Touch Emulator](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator) has any release for Windows computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can just install Ubuntu, which is free to use and to download, and use that to develop.

Comment: I already have Ubuntu with Ubuntu Touch Emulator. I have a computer with Windows and i also search if i can run it.